# How to resize images to fill the row using css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple images which I want to show using flexbox. But the images leave a gap if the next image cannot fit in the same row.

[image: Wrong Output]

I want these images to resize accordingly so that there is no gap left.

Example:

[image: Desired Output]

HTML:

```
<div class="ImageContainer">
    <div class="ImageBlock">
        <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/246/739/689/digital-digital-art-artwork-illustration-abstract-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg"
            alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageBlock">
        <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/410/867/750/vector-forest-sunset-forest-sunset-forest-wallpaper-thumb.jpg"
            alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageBlock">
        <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg"
            alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageBlock">
        <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/39/346/426/digital-art-men-city-futuristic-night-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg"
            alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ImageContainer{
    margin:40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ImageBlock{
    margin:10px;
}

.ImageBlock img{
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: `.ImageBlock{
  flex-grow:1;
}` ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `flex-grow: 1;` to the `.ImageBlock`

This will make the block expand.

```
.ImageBlock {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Then you will have to make the `img` fill the block with `width: 100%;`

If you don't want the image to stretch out of proportions, you can use `object-fit: cover;`.

```
.ImageBlock img {
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/rNMVrVL

Comment: but it only allows 2 images in a row and I want it to be expandable up to n number of images depending on the window size.

Comment: It does depend on the window size, try zooming further out, and you will more images per row.

Comment: my screen resolution is 1366x768 and it only displays 2 images in row 1 and only 1 image in row 2,3,4. Is there a way to display at least 2 to 3 images per row for my resolution and change later on responsively?

Comment: Yes, right now it depends on the images native src. The images you link to are 551px wide, so it cannot fit 3 in one row, on 1366px screen width.

You can simply add width styling to the elements: `width: 25%;` will give you 4 elements in a row, `width: 33.3333%;` will give you 3 elements in a row, and so on.

Comment: what can I do to achieve this result: https://ibb.co/dmXkr5Q with my resolution as most of the people have this resolution

Comment: Maybe this is the solution you are looking for? https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/rNMVrVL